# How can I dynamically apply Lightweight styling to NavigationView?

Tags: winrt-xaml, winui-3

Changing the NavigationViewContentMargin dynamically, which determines the top margin of the NavigationView, does not change the appearance of the NavigationView dynamically.

Is there a way to dynamically change the top margin of NavigationView from the code?

[top margin of NavigationView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzKxE.png)

Comment: Change the Margin resource for example [NavigationViewItemInnerHeaderMargin](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/cb181acede22577c59c5dc250361d3340252f4e9/dev/NavigationView/NavigationView.xaml#L810) or the [Margin value](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/cb181acede22577c59c5dc250361d3340252f4e9/dev/NavigationView/NavigationView.xaml#L814) programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the target `Grid` "NavigationViewContentMargin" is applied to. This `Grid` is named "ContentGrid".

The tricky part is that `NavigationViews` have 2 Grids with the name "ContentGrid". The "ContentGrid" we need is the one that is inside a `Grid` with the name "ContentRoot". BTW, the other one is inside "Settings".

First, we need to get the "ContentRoot" `Grid`, then get the "ContentGrid" we need.

Check this example:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="NavigationViewTests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:NavigationViewTests"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Thickness x:Key="NavigationViewContentMargin">0,48,0,0</Thickness>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <NavigationView
            x:Name="NavigationViewControl"
            Grid.Column="0"
            IsBackButtonVisible="Visible">
            <TextBlock Text="Content" />
        </NavigationView>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <NumberBox
                x:Name="NavigationViewContentGridTopMarginNumber"
                Header="NavigationView Top Margin"
                ValueChanged="NumberBox_ValueChanged" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Linq;

namespace NavigationViewTests;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationViewControl.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.NavigationViewContentGrid = GetNavigationViewContentGridInsideContentGrid();

            if (this.NavigationViewContentGrid is not null)
            {
                this.NavigationViewContentGridTopMarginNumber.Value = this.NavigationViewContentGrid.Margin.Top;
            }
        };
    }

    private Grid? NavigationViewContentGrid { get; set; }

    private Grid? GetNavigationViewContentGridInsideContentGrid()
    {
        Grid? contentRoot = this.NavigationViewControl
            .FindChildrenOfType<Grid>()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "ContentRoot")
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return contentRoot?
           .FindChildrenOfType<Grid>()
           .Where(x => x.Name == "ContentGrid")
           .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private void NumberBox_ValueChanged(NumberBox _, NumberBoxValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (NavigationViewContentGrid is not null)
        {
            Thickness currentMargin = this.NavigationViewContentGrid.Margin;
            this.NavigationViewContentGrid.Margin = new Thickness(
                currentMargin.Left,
                args.NewValue,
                currentMargin.Right,
                currentMargin.Bottom);
        }
    }
}
```